# Bounds on Frobenius norm of inverse of an eigenvector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Suppose that $A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is diagonalizable with possibly complex eigenvalues. Is it possible to find an upperbound $R$ for $\|Q\|_F\|Q^{-1}\|_F < R$ that works for any $A$?

I have tried the following. I can find a lower bound using the submultiplicative property of matrix norm

$$\|Q\|_F\|Q^{-1}\|_F \geq \|Q Q^{-1}\|_F = \|I\|_F = \sqrt{n}.$$

Without loss of generality, assume that the eigenvector matrix contains normalized eigenvectors. In this case, 
$$\|Q\|^2_F = \sum_{i=1}^n \|Q_i\|^2_2 = n \Rightarrow |Q\|_F = \sqrt{n}$$

If $A$ is symmetric, $Q^{-1} = Q^T$ and $\|Q\|_F\|Q^{-1}\|_F = n $. Therefore, $R$ must be at least $n$.  But, how can I find a bound for $\|Q^{-1}\|_F$ for general $A$?